# How to use Fancybox 5 to show a photo when clicking a Leaflet marker

Tags: leaflet, fancybox, google-maps-markers

Is this possible at all?
This is my code so far

```
var marker = L.geoJSON(geojsonFeatureCamera, {
              pointToLayer: function (feature, latlng) {
               return L.circleMarker(latlng, geojsonMarkerOptionsCamera);
              },
              onEachFeature: function(feature, layer) {
               layer.on('mouseover', function(e) {
                do_something();
               });
              }
             });
```

I am able to do_something. E.g. open een Popup or write something to console.
But I would like to open an image (of which the name is in feature.image) with FancyBox 5.
And I am totally stuck on how to do that.
Can somebody help me with this?

Thanks in advance!

Could not find any results regarding Fancybox5 in Google.

Comment: Check out examples here - https://fancyapps.com/fancybox/plugins/images/#programmatic

Comment: Thanks. I saw this doc. Bu I still have no clue how to use this from a Javascript-function.

Comment: If `feature.show` is a link to image, then it would be as simple as `Fancybox.show([{ src: feature.show} ]);`.  If you want to know how to add click event, then try googling "leaflet marker click event", you will find samples.

Comment: Wow! You made my day. And so simple.
But, could I have learned this from https://fancyapps.com/fancybox/?
Thanks again!

Comment: <shame on>
Yes I could have learned. From the link you provided in your first answer
<shame off>